# Llamar a un controlador desde una vista que pertenece a otro controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

He creado un proyecto en VS 2017 con Scaffolding (CRUD) ha creado las vistas. Pero ahora como puedo llamar al controlador del CRUD dentro del proyecto que crea por defecto VS,

Coloco en la URL el nombre del controlador y funciona, pero necesito llamarlo de un botón o un enlace.

**Este es el típico proyecto que genera VS. haciendo uso del controlador home. pero dentro de esta vista, ¿ es posible llamar a otro controlador?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar una sobrecarga de ActionLink

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Texto del Link","Acción","Controlador",null,null)
```

Aclaro que el primero de los null hace referencia a un objeto de tipo `routValues` por si tenés que pasar algún parámetro, y el segundo a un objeto `htmlAttributes` por si queres manejar el más fino su html

Saludos

Comment: No necesitas agregar `null, null` al final, a menos que vayas a poner un atributo HTML en el último argumento.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!